# Connecting solar cells directly to battery

Tags: circuit-design, battery-charging, solar-cell, mppt

I'm building a solar powered RC plane and need to design a power system to deliver power from the solar panels to the battery and motor.

I have an array of 38 C60 solar cells outputting 22.8V (0.6*38), and a 5S LiPo battery with a voltage of 18.5-21V. The problem is MPPT charge controllers are expensive and heavy, so I'm wondering if I can just hook them up directly with a diode to prevent reverse current through the solar cells.

From what I've read, the panels are supposed to match themselves to the voltage they are connected to, so even if they aren't at maximum efficiency they will be the correct voltage to the charge the battery. So if this is the case is there any risk of overcharging? And would this be detrimental to the battery health? There will also be times when the motor is drawing more power than the solar cells can provide; will the excess power be safely drawn from the battery in this situation?

Otherwise what other ways could I safely connect them together, preferably without using an MPPT charger?

Comment: I know weight is crucial in RC planes, but what do you consider "heavy"? How big is your plane?

Comment: What's the max open circuit voltage of your PV array?

Comment: MPPT charge controllers don't have to be heavy, it's just that most products are meant for residential solar and (likely) considerably oversized for you application. It would be useful to know the panel power and battery capacity on your RC plane.

Comment: @PMF The plane weighs around 3kg without the MPPT, and from what I've seen online they tend to weigh around 500g which is quite significant. I'm not sure how much could be saved by removing their casing and heatsinks.

Comment: @winny Voc=0.713V so as hobbs answered the solar voltage could be substantially higher

Comment: @DamienD That's true, I'm hoping that I'll be able to save some weight by removing the casing and heatsink from whatever I end up buying. The maximum power is 135W at 1000W/m^2, and the battery capacity is 5000mAh.

Comment: @Dorphen I suggest googling for "MPPT PCB" or maybe even "MPPT PCB 8A" (try with various current ratings around your needs). There's a bunch of options around.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> From what I've read, the panels are supposed to match themselves to the voltage they are connected to, so even if they aren't at maximum efficiency they will be the correct voltage to the charge the battery.

No. Yes, the V/I curve does mean that the voltage sort of "follows the battery" in the specific case that the device attached to the panel is a battery, but it *doesn't* mean that the voltage will always be "correct" or safe.

> So if this is the case is there any risk of overcharging?

Yes, if the battery is full or near-full and there is sun, the solar panel will try to force the battery up to its Voc and damage it. 22.8V would be bad enough, but based on some quick research I think your "0.6V" cells are actually 0.6V near the MPP, and they have a Voc of around 0.72V, so the whole series string would be over 27V — *way* too much.

> And would this be detrimental to the battery health?

Yes. Overcharging, even a little, degrades the battery rapidly. Overcurrent is also bad for the battery and risks a fire. I don't know how big your battery is or what its charge current rating is, but if it's under 6A then you have another problem.

> There will also be times when the motor is drawing more power than the solar cells can provide

*This* is fine, that's why you have a battery. As long as it's protected from over-discharge you're good.

> Otherwise what other ways could I safely connect them together, preferably without using an MPPT charger?

The only *really* safe and sane way to charge a lithium battery is with a lithium battery charger, and if the source is solar you want it to be an MPPT charger.

The only other way I know of is to make the solar cells too small — make the series string short enough that the total Voc is less than 4.2V/cell, and make the area small enough that Isc is less than your batteries' rated current capacity. But that's not very appealing — it means that your battery will never be full, and will only start to accept significant power from the solar once it's discharged quite a bit. Which means you're wasting weight in a different way, by carrying around battery that never gets used to its full capacity, and solar that sits around doing nothing! The device that makes sure you're getting the best energy/weight out of both your battery and your solar is... an MPPT charger.

Also note that even if you do take the "undersized solar cell" approach you *still* need protection circuitry for safety's sake.

Comment: The Voc is usually given at 25°C and increases when it's colder, that's another factor to take into account for a safe margin.

Comment: If there is a circuit to prevent undercharging, with a slight modification it might be able to protect against overcharging (over voltage?) as well, which saves an MPPT device. But I agree with whoever said that a 135 W MPPT might not have to weigh too much (but I haven't looked it up). But also, on a moving plane, the fluctuations in insolation might be too fast for the MPPT to keep up with.

Answer (score 0):

Not a direct answer to your question here—see @hobbs for that—but,...

> From what I've read, the panels are supposed to match themselves to the voltage they are connected to, so even if they aren't at maximum efficiency they will be the correct voltage to the charge the battery.

That might not mean what you think it means.

It does *not* mean that the panels know the safe voltage limits for the battery or, the recommended charging voltage. It does not mean that the voltage of the battery won't change when you make the connection. What it means is, any time you connect two or more two-terminal devices in parallel, you are *forcing* the voltage across all of the devices to be the same.

That's in accordance with [Kirchoff's Voltage Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_circuit_laws#Kirchhoff%27s_voltage_law).

Forcing a voltage across a device usually causes current and power to flow. How much current/power? Which way does it flow? What is the forced voltage?... Those answers can vary a lot depending on the kinds of devices that you're connecting together. At any given instant, it's something you can predict from the [Current-Voltage Characteristics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Current%E2%80%93voltage_characteristic) of the devices. But it can be complicated by the fact that the current-voltage characteristic of a device might not be constant. For a battery, the CV graph changes as the battery's state of charge changes. For a solar panel, it changes with the strength of the illumination.

@hobbs's answer speaks more to the specific case of a solar panel paralleled with a battery bank, but for whatever it's worth,...

A "smart" battery charger isolates it's input side from its output side. The voltages and currents on the two sides can be different from each other. On the output side, it tries to force a voltage and current that meet the needs of a known type and configuration of batteries. On the input side, an MPPT controller seeks the operating point on the solar panel's CV graph that gives the most power.